# Dual screen issue with Nvidia Graphic card on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have no problem when I have one display only, either of laptop or monitor. However, screen stretches as you see in the screenshot and is not clickable in order to change the settings. My laptop is Lenovo P50,  with Nvidia Quadro M2000M as its graphic card.

[image]

My Software and updates looks like following screenshot.
[image]

And `Nvidia` is selected in PRIME.
[image]

What I have done:

1. I have selected `nvidia-370` and `nvidia-367` as well. However I got similar experience.
2. I selected `X.Org X server`. I had no problem with having two screens at the same time (beside each other). However, quality was very poor. I could see graphic issue when I scroll browser up/bottom or even see footprints of mouse when I was move it.
3. I downloaded the driver from [nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com/download/find.aspx) and installed it via the script. However, it messed up my system and I reinstalled the OS, Ubuntu :)
4. I followed, https://askubuntu.com/a/760935/143703, and tried to install the driver via TTY. No success at the end.
5. I bought a Display Port to HDMI converter, however there was no difference.

So, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: (1) and (4) as expected and redundant. However, there's something to retain from the linked anser, the need to purge Nvidia drivers before attempting a new version. (2) also expected and (3) also expected and do not do that. Only **375** is recommended by Nvidia for your chipset. As such, from a **clean** system, follow the accepted answer from your link. Do not touch the drivers again. Whatever troubleshooting may need to be done it should only be done with that condition and no other from the start.